# Android OutOfMemoryError in SetContentView line

Tags: android

When i try to open my chat class , sometimes it runs properly , sometimes it gives OutOfMemoryError at setContentView line.I can't understand what is the cause of problem?
Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarmesajlasma"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:elevation="1dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutmesajlasma"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00000000">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:src="@mipmap/geribas" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_width="43dp"
                    android:layout_height="43dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="135dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                    android:text="Abdurrahman"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarmesajlasma"
            android:background="@mipmap/maybehi">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="#00000000"
                android:dividerHeight="4dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/bisiler_yaz_altplan"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bisiler_yaz"
                    android:hint="Bir mesaj yaz..."
                    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:capitalize="sentences"
                    android:allowUndo="true"
                    android:width="295dp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:src="@mipmap/gonder"
                    android:text="Gonder"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivYatay"
        android:src="@drawable/horizontalrope"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivCapraz"
        android:src="@drawable/diagonalrope"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:background="@mipmap/gri"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3708)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
  at droxoft.armin.com.shappy.Mesajlasma.onCreate(Mesajlasma.java:223)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you loading images from server? Replace your image loading library with Picasso or Glide libraries

Comment: ypu need to increase heap size check below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072456/2826147

Answer (score 4):

Your OOM error is related to the Images you are loading as I am seeing in your log trace.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for  loading large Bitmaps more efficiently:

A 400 KB image file can easily take up 5-10 MB of RAM.

For requesting to incraese heap size dynamically, Use `android:largeHeap="true"`
in the manifest.xml.

or/and just use the proper function to decode...

Answer (score 2):

I would check the size of all your images referred to in your ImageViews. If they are large, maybe encode them as different image types to reduce the image size. The Android system is periodically running out of memory and crashing your application currently. It makes sense that you are getting this only sometimes as it depends on how much memory is currently being used for other applications etc... . If you reduce the size of your images significantly you should be able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the gradle.properties in the root of your project :

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m`

the default jvmargs is 256

you can request to use more by using.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in the manifest.xml.