# Cannot solve out of memory error when loading from gallery

Tags: android, memory

This problem doesn't occur on my phone because it has a ram of 2 gb but there are a lot of mobiles that have a ram of 1 gb and this problem occurs almost every time on such a mobile . Every time image in loaded from gallery and placed on an imageview it crash with an outofmemory error.

This is my code . I get the width height of the image and then scale the image but still doesn't work. I also use picasso because it works asynchronously.

```
public static void setGalleryImageWithPicasso(Activity context, Uri imageURI, int image, final PicassoBitmapCallBack callBack) {
    int MAX_WIDTH =500;
    int MAX_HEIGHT =500;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    String filePath = getPath(imageURI, context);
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    int width = options.outWidth;
    int height = options.outHeight;

    while (width > MAX_WIDTH && height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width = (width * 2) / 3;
        height = (height * 2) / 3;
    }
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageURI)
                .resize(width, height)
                .centerInside()
                .placeholder(image)
                .error(image)
                .into(new Target() {

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded (Bitmap bmp, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){  
                        // Place image on imageview etc
                        callBack.onSuccess(bmp);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
}

public static String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    int columnIndex = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    }
    String filePath = null;
    if (cursor != null) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

I looked into insample size and checked a lot but wasn't able to understand it so plz can someone post modifications to my code and not give me links . And i don't understand 500 * 500 is pretty small but i still get the same error.

Comment: The problem is not with the target size but the original size that needs to be loaded as a bitmap in memory in order to convert it to a smaller size.

Comment: i don't understand , isn't that what i am doing?

Comment: I always had one thing in my mind . Am i directly first loading the image onto the memory and than i am scaling it??

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan:  There is no way to convert it other than loading the full image as a bitmap.  If your clients run out of memory, you need to provide smaller images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: @JuliePelletier i cannot force the users to select smaller images from gallery , i must be doing something wrong because i once tried it with an image with wdth height of approx 150 * 240 and i still got the exception.

Comment: Aren't you talking about your own library?

Comment: meaning my own?? User can select any image from gallery to put as a picture.

Comment: Is that gallery on your own system or not?

Comment: offcourse not . Every user has his own gallery of images on his phone

Comment: Note that the size, resolution and color depth combined determine the memory needed.

Comment: refer my solution..may it help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072179/6097062

Comment: How do you call your `setGalleryImageWithPicasso`? Nothing is wrong with the above code. I guess the problem comes from the other part of your code.

Comment: `There is no way to convert it other than loading the full image as a bitmap.`.  Are you talking about how Picasso behaves? As this is not true for BitmapFactory.decodeFile().

Comment: so what am i doing wrong . I debugged my app , works fine on my phone ( because of ram ) but crashes on other phone . Once i tried to load an image with width height of 200 and it still crashed :/