# Nested RecyclerView wrap_content causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-wrap-content

I have a `NestedScrollView`, it contains a `RecyclerView` `wrap_content`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
  layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
  rvStream.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  rvStream.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And when I use it to load list of images (using picasso), I got memory leak:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation
>   with 0 free bytes and -3040B until OOM

How to avoid it, I'm also using lazy loading

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072179/6097062

Comment: My guess is that putting a Recycler in a ScrollView will result in the Recycler "thinking" thank all of it is visible. It will therefore create adapter.getCount() of ViewHolders and call Picasso on each and every one of them.

Comment: if you are working with images in a list or grid views.. then definitely you need to keep mobile compatible low resolution images.