# adding images in ListView shows out of memory

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating the listView that contains image and text but unfortunately it will work for adding three images more than that it shows out of memory.I saw many questions like the same.but still i dint get any clear idea how to call the Bitmap functions within my code.

My code is here, help me to complete this task.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] titles;
ListView list1;

int [] img = {R.drawable.meal11,R.drawable.meal12,R.drawable.mrngs1,R.drawable.mrngs2,R.drawable.lunch1,R.drawable.lunch2};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    titles = new String[]{"BANANA & BERRY SMOOTHIE","COTTAGE CHEESE, AVOCADO & TOMATO TOAST","FRITTATA CAKES","CHOC PROTEIN BALLS","CHICKEN & SUNDRIED TOMATO SALAD","TUNA WRAP"};

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(),titles,img);

    list1.setAdapter(adapter);




}

class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] imgs;
    String[] titles;
    myAdapter(Context context,String[] titles,int imgs[]) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_item,R.id.text,titles);
        this.context= context;
        this.imgs = imgs;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        TextView myText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);

        myImage.setImageResource(imgs[position]);

        myText.setText(titles[position]);

        return row;
    }
}}
```

xml code for mainActiviy.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.sa.addimagelistview.MainActivity"
android:padding="0dp">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list">

</ListView>
```

xml code for list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/meal11"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/texttitle"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look on this...http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072179/6097062

Comment: make use of convertview

Comment: @saurabh it used that code also. but again it shows out of memory

Comment: @sarthak how to use it

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92 check the getView() method

Comment: have look on this article http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @sushildlh i will read this article.

Comment: @Rathiga Jesika  This is because your images meal12.mrngs1 etc are big in sizes.

Comment: @Nisarg how to change the images in same size

Comment: @RathigaJesika You need to use [this](https://tinypng.com/) for compress images if you want to else if that wont work you can handle it in coding

Comment: @Nisarg thanks for your help. do you have any idea about list view scroll is not properly working while adding many images?

Comment: @RathigaJesika Welcome :) Post your xml ?

Comment: @Nisarg now i added my xml code also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115274/discussion-between-nisarg-and-rathiga-jesika).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that, images you are trying to add in your listview are large and after a certain time they exceed the default memory provided by android. 
To over come this you have to scale the images down to the size you actually want them in

You can use Piccaso which does the scaling work on its own if you use `fit()`

All you have to do is this.

add the Picasso dependency in your gradle `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

and then try this

```
Picasso
  .with(context)
  .load(your_image)
  .fit()
  // call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
  .into(your_imageview);
```

Comment: Your Welcome :), updated my answer with a little more detail. hope it works for you.

Comment: nope, for text, `setText` works fine. though i have a tip on the way you are storing your data to be displayed. Instead of using two arrays, a single ArrayList is much efficent. For eg make a class with 2 variable (int and String) in your case. then inside its Constructor pass parameters for int and String. and later make a `Arraylist<MyClass>` (my class is the class which has int and String). now add your data in arraylist like this. `arraylist.add(new MyClass(your_int_image,your_text_title));` you can get the data from your arraylist like this `arraylist.get(position).image`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of picasso...

```
  Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imgs[position])//load images into imageview
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_file)//default image
                    .into(myImage);
```

Comment: more images it takes more time to scroll how to solve this problem

Comment: Actually the real problem is the "/drawable" folder! you have all the pictures in "/drawable" generic folder that is considered by the system like "/drawable/mdpi", so when you are running in devices with hdpi or more the images were resized, and became too big which cause OutOfMemoryException!

Now just use  "/drawable-nodpi" to store your images. This folder works like "/drawable" but the images are never resized! @RathigaJesika

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setImageResource() directly but, use libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which loads image very smoothly and do image caching to load it fast.

Glide Compile Line -  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Picasso Compile Line - compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Glide Example:

```
Glide.with(context).load(imgs[position]).into(myImage);
```

Picasso Exaple:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imgs[position]).into(myImage);
```

If you don't want to use libraries try this [official Android Link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: thanks for this idea.. this show six item text after that unfortunately stopped. error like :android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: You can use ViewHolder Pattern to increase performance. Link - https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html Link - 2 https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview

Comment: adding this line  android:largeHeap="true" in manifest showing all the items.but it takes more time to scroll the list items. i don't know what to do

Comment: The issue is because your drawables are of very high resolution. Have you tried ViewHolder Pattern? because it decreases call of findViewById()

Comment: Can you attach your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

put in Mainfest--->

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
    >
.....
   </application>
```

may it will help

Comment: more images it takes more time to scroll how to solve this problem

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html there is a solution for it..

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modification on your adapter please try this one hope it would help :D

```
class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] imgs;
    String[] titles;
    myAdapter(Context context,String[] titles,int imgs[]) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_item,R.id.text,titles);
        this.context= context;
        this.imgs = imgs;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView!=null){
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }else{
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }


        holder.myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        holder.myText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);

        myImage.setImageResource(imgs[position]);

        myText.setText(titles[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    // somewhere else in your class definition
    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView myImage;
        TextView myText;    
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) is Reference for ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It worked for me if I just opened the image in Gimp, scaled it down and exported it with loss of quality so that it took up less space.

Should be some better solution though since the image I had was only a couple of megabytes in the first place.